# canvas js dates are repeating on x axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, canvasjs

I am using `canvasjs` for showing data in chart format. all is working fine beside dates are

repeating when there is less data.

Here is my JS

```
var chartResponses = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartResponses", {
        animationEnabled: true,
        toolTip: {
            enabled: true,
            animationEnabled: true,
            fontColor: "#F9BF97",
        },
        axisX: {
            titleFontFamily: "verdana",
            valueFormatString: "D/M/YYYY",
            tickThickness: 0,
            lineThickness: 1,
            gridThickness: 0,
            gridColor: "#f2f6f7",
            lineColor: "#f2f6f7",
            labelFontColor: "#8fa2aa",
            labelFontSize: 12,
            intervalType: "day",

        },
        axisY: {
            titleFontFamily: "verdana",
            valueFormatString: "0",
            tickThickness: 0,
            lineThickness: 0,
            gridThickness: 1,
            gridColor: "#f2f6f7",
            lineColor: "#f2f6f7",
            labelFontColor: "#8fa2aa",
            labelFontSize: 12
        },
        data: [{
                type: "splineArea",
                showInLegend: true,
                markerSize: 0,
                name: "",
                color: "#F9BF97",
                dataPoints: allResponses
            }],
    });

    chartResponses.render();
```

and this how it show chart when I have only two dates

[image]

I tried with setting interval to `interval: 1`. In this case less data charts are working fine but when I have more data dates are started overlapping like below image.

[image]

But when I remove `interval: 1` then it show fine

[image]

So is there any way to solve this issue.

Comment: is it possible for you to add a fiddle? with datapoints hard coded

Comment: `jsfiddle` blocking http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js. So not able to create. if you want try http://jsfiddle.net/hb5KU/11/ and change `type: "splineArea",` and create more records of date and check

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the interval property by 5 or more when you have more data or else change the intervalType property by week or month. as shown in this updated fiddle. jsfiddle.net/hb5KU/66/

You can add it in future before rendering the chart according to your response data length.

Comment: @urfusion,
For dynamically changing interval you can get ideas from -http://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/8e98Lej8/
Here instead of intrvalType you can set interval.
Also for initial render(without zooming) you have find viewportMinimum and viewportMaximum from your data and apply it accordingly.